# Android - Get the current location not working

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I have the problem with getting the LocationManager object. The code should work on all Android API but while my tests I found that LocationManager isn't null only in 25 API.

```
   fun invokeLocalization(): Location? {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        val locationManager = ctx.applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
        if ( ctx.checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            var bestLocation: Location? = null
            for (provider in locationManager.getProviders(true)) {
                val location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider) ?: continue
                if (bestLocation == null || location.accuracy < bestLocation.accuracy) bestLocation = location
            }
            return bestLocation
        } else {
            (ctx as AddAlertActivity).requestPermissions(arrayOf(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            return locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

And my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
```

Premission is enabled for localization in android's settings.
[image]

I will be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use FusedLocation API from google which got updated location or last known location

https://developers.google.com/location-context/fused-location-provider/

Comment: I change code as you wrote. And it is wired because it's working on my mobile but on emulators, "it" returns null.
`await((ctx as AddAlertActivity).fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
     .addOnSuccessListener { location = it })`

Comment: in emulator, you have put custom latlng in its settings.

Comment: Yes, I know. But I was thinking that default position should be return by the object. Now it's working. Thanks!